# How to loop through CSV to read and extract ranking according to one column?

Tags: python, loops, pivot-table

I feel that I am going to ask a very basic question, but please bear with me.

I have 3 CSV files. I want to find the best and worst of a specific column.
I did for one CSV, somehow.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

path = r"MyFolder"
file1 = '59107_20210630m.csv'
file2 = '65758_20210630m.csv'
file3 = '26389_20210630m.csv'

d1 = os.path.join(path,file1)
d2 = os.path.join(path,file2)
d3 = os.path.join(path,file3)

df1 = pd.read_csv(d1,dtype={'Fund':str, 'Identifier':str, 'Product Description':str, 'L/S':str},thousands=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv(d2,dtype={'Fund':str, 'Identifier':str, 'Product Description':str, 'L/S':str},thousands=',')
df3= pd.read_csv(d3,dtype={'Fund':str, 'Identifier':str, 'Product Description':str, 'L/S':str},thousands=',')



Best_Contributors = df1.sort_values('Net MTD P&L (Base)',
                                    ascending=False).reset_index().head()[['Fund', 'Identifier', 'Product Description', 'L/S',
                                                             '% exp of NAV','Period % (Base)','Net MTD P&L (Base)','Contribution (bps)' ]]

Worst_Contributors = df1.sort_values('Net MTD P&L (Base)').reset_index().head()[['Fund', 'Identifier', 'Product Description', 'L/S',
                                                                   '% exp of NAV','Period % (Base)','Net MTD P&L (Base)','Contribution (bps)']]

Fund = df1.iloc[0,0]
Fund
```

'59107'

```
Best_Contributors.style.set_caption(Fund+"        Best_Contributors")
```

```
                                59107 Best_Contributors
    Fund    Identifier  Product Description               L/S   % exp of NAV    Period % (Base) Net MTD P&L (Base)  Contribution (bps)  
0   59107   4523 JP Equity  EISAI CO LTD                L   1.3             4.67        44  5.41060
1   59107   9517 JP Equity  EREX CO LTD                 L   1.2             4.22        43  5.47042
2   59107   7203 JP Equity  TOYOTA MOTOR CORP           L   4.5             6.53        22  2.42082
3   59107   3382 JP Equity  SEVEN & I HOLDINGS CO LTD   L   2.3             1.68        18  2.45396
4   59107   6501 JP Equity  HITACHI LTD                 L   1.9             1.01        17  2.51208
```

```
Worst_Contributors .style.set_caption(Fund+"        Worst_Contributors")
```

```
                             59107 Worst_Contributors
    Fund    Identifier  Product Description                L/S  % exp of NAV    Period % (Base) Net MTD P&L (Base)  Contribution (bps)
0   59107   6301 JP Equity  KOMATSU LTD                 L   1.4           -1.40     -1680   -21.12414
1   59107   9984 JP Equity  SOFTBANK GROUP CORP         L   1.8           -5.94     -114    -14.41187
2   59107   3678 JP Equity  MEDIA DO HOLDINGS CO LTD    L   0.0           -1.90     -1133   -14.24195
3   59107   8630 JP Equity  SOMPO HOLDINGS INC          L   1.7           -6.36     -9766   -12.27612
4   59107   8750 JP Equity  DAI-ICHI LIFE HOLDINGS INC  L   1.2           -8.01     -931    -11.70994
```

How can I make it in a loop, to get 6 tables (dataframe) at once? Basically one set of Best_Contributors and Worst_Contributors for each fund.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that the rendering is done using HTML in which case multiple spaces are treated as a single space.

Comment: if you display in HTML (on web page) then you will need `&nbsp;` (`non-breaking space`) instead of every space.

Comment: your title doesn't fit to your problem with spaces. Title is misleading.